# FFMPEG Add watermark to MP4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this command to add watermark to an mp4

```
ffmpeg -i junai-blvaz.mp4 -i evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

But I am creating the video using

```
ffmpeg -r 6 -i /tmp/%d.jpg -c:v h264_nvenc -r 6 -preset slow -bufsize 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -y junai-blvaz.mp4
```

Is there any way to merge this command of adding watermark

```
-i evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10'
```

to the very first command through which mp4 video has been created?

Comment: why are you giving a minus to all my FFMPEG questions? what is wrong in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two commands:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 6 -i /tmp/%d.jpg -i evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10,format=yuv420p" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -bufsize 1000k junai-blvaz.mp4
```

Comment: why you replace -r with framerate?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq `-framerate`, not `-r`, is the proper input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).

Comment: can I know the reason for being -1? always on question?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I'm guessing whoever voted to close it as off-topic also downvoted. Officially, non-programming questions are off-topic here and should be asked at [su] instead.

Comment: Hi , how I can use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` instead of `format=yuv420p` because of this, the created video is not being played in VLC any more.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq That shouldn't be the problem because `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is just an alias for `format=yuv420p`, but to answer your question just remove `,format=yuv420p` and add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before your output file name. I recommend asking a new question at [su] so we can see what the real problem is. Make sure to show your command and the complete log.

Comment: Okay sure, I have tried that but it didnt work either